# Cron not working, although the command works

Tags: 18.04, themes, cron, gtk3, gsettings

My crontab is like as follows (I am trying to change my GNOME theme)

```
crontab -l
0 5 * * * /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adapta'
30 21 * * *  /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adapta-Nokto'
```

Also, I created this file

```
echo $USER
nikhil
cat /etc/cron.allow
nikhil
```

When I run the command as mentioned in crontab, both of those work.

Could you please tell if I missed out some step?

---

Edit:

I created a script file, which I execute with cron:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
TimeHr=$(date +%H)
if ((${TimeHr}>18 || ${TimeHr}<5)); then
#if [${TimeHr} -gt 11 || ${TimeHr} -lt 5]; then
    mkdir ${HOME}/Documents/TestNight
    /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adapta'
else
    mkdir ${HOME}/Documents/TestDay
    /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adapta-Nokto'
fi
```

This is crontab

```
$ crontab -l
36 5,19,23 * * * bash /home/nikhil/GnomeThemeChange
@reboot bash /home/nikhil/GnomeThemeChange
```

`cron` does work as it is able to create Test Folders. But, what should I do to run `gsettings` inside cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tomáš Pospíšek for the suggestions.

Add the following to the script:

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session | tail -n1)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
```

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure cron is not working? If you add a line like

```
 */1 * * * * touch /tmp/foobar123
```

to your crontab, then does the file appear in `/tmp`?

If that file won't appear after a minute or so, then

```
ps auxw | grep cron
```

or

```
sudo service cron status
```

If cron is not running, then try to start it with

```
sudo service cron start
```

But I guess the problem with your command above is, that `gsettings` needs to have its environment set up correctly in order to run, which it probably does not have, when run from `cron`.